# How to open PDF file with Docx in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, docx, converters

I want to open a pdf file from my mac, but I get this error:

'This file can't be opened. It's possible damaged or has a document structure which Preview doesn't recognize.'

This is the code I'm using:

```
from docx import Document
#open the document
doc=Document('./testDoc.docx')
a = input('Whats your name ')
b = input('Whats your date of birth ')

Dictionary = {"name": a, "dob": b}

for i in Dictionary:
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        if p.text.find(i)>=0:
            p.text=p.text.replace(i,Dictionary[i])

#save changed document
doc.save('/my/path/contract{}.pdf'.format(a))
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: python-docx cannot export to pdf. you could try [this](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/113#issuecomment-455814436)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think the `docx` module works for pdfs--there's nothing in their documentation about it. But you can use the `docx2pdf` module instead: https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/

Here's the simple how-to that's in their documentation:

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

`docx` module cannot convert word document to PDF.
You can use `pywin32` module.

```
import win32com.client
def wordToPdf(input_path, output_path):
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    doc = word.Documents.Open(str(input_path))
    doc.SaveAs(str(output_path), FileFormat=17)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```